# I need to hide a H2 of a widget

Tags: css, display

I have a blog where I use the affiliate links of GetYourGuide.
In particular, I use it in this page:
https://www.visitare.net/best-tours-in-bologna/

I insert the affiliate widget through the HTML widget of Elementor, and it comes with a very annoying `H2` header:
[image: The written "Unforgettable experiences I recommend " has to go!]

I tried to delete it with CSS:

```
.title-banner {display:none;} 
.title-banner[data-v-48b40ecd] {display:none;}
```

and I also used `!important`, but nothing worked

This problem also repeats each time I use this affiliate links, I don't understand why GetYourGuide has to insert a headline that should be personal based on the blog.

Comment: Please share more details, like the markup involved

Comment: `.title-banner[data-v-48b40ecd] {display:none;}` should work fine, provided it comes after the already existing rules (because there is one with the same selector, that sets `display: flex`). If you can't do anything about the order, then `.title-banner {display:none !important;}` should also work.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Those are the 2 lines I tried but none of them worked. They both come after the existing rule. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Keep in mind that all those items are opened in an iframe. Therefore, you have to add `.title-banner {display:none !important;}` in the right place.

Comment: Thank you, and in the case of Elementor HTML widget, which one is the right place?

Comment: After revisiting your page, I noticed that the content is loaded from an external domain. And this is also the problem. In my comment I assumed that all these `<iframe>` elements load **content from the same domain**. Long story short, there is no way to edit a cross domain `<iframe>`. You can manipulate domains within the same level or lower in your domain chain but not for the given situation, that would be **Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)**, which is prohibited for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start reading here, **please read my comments** under the OP's question.

After some thought and as a last resort, it could be done with some sort of workaround. It's just an idea and maybe it will get to the point, especially when it comes to mobile views, where it doesn't make sense anymore. You'll just have to experiment around there.

So what's it all about? The idea is to put the `<iframe>` in a *container*, set  to `position: absolute;` and pull it up a bit with a **negative value** for `margin-top`. Finally, we also need the `clip-path` property to mask it. **NOTE:** This is what you need to do for each `<iframe>`, e.g. *Top sights in Bologna*, *Best Food Tours*, etc.

For a better understanding here is a very brief example. The gray area is virtually the *container*. Of course, it can have the same `height` as the `<iframe>` and is only larger for demonstration purposes. The red area, on the other hand, is supposed to represent the `<iframe>`. Finally, the *Lorem Ipsum* placeholder text simply represents any arbitrary content. In your case, of course, this would be the images.

I think putting the `<iframe>` into a *container* and then applying the CSS rules from below **should be possible with Elementor**.

```css
.iframe-container {
    width: 480px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.iframe-dummy {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 460px;
    background: red;
}

.iframe-dummy h2 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.iframe-dummy p {
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
}

/* THE WORKAROUND CLASS (see AFTER example in HTML) */

.workaround {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -45px;
    clip-path: margin-box;
}
```

```html
<h2>Before:</h2>
<div class="iframe-container">
    <div class="iframe-dummy">
        <h2>Annoying Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2>After:</h2>
<div class="iframe-container">
    <div class="iframe-dummy workaround">
        <h2>Annoying Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT (in reference to a comment by the OP):

> Can you show me a practical example directly for my [website](https://www.visitare.net/best-tours-in-bologna/)?

I took another look at your [website](https://www.visitare.net/best-tours-in-bologna/) and found that a suitable *container* already exists. Besides that, you can also omit setting `position: absolute;`. I have to mention that by not having custom class names or IDs, I had to fall back on what was there. I'll come back to that later.

**First, here is the required CSS:**

```
/* Column containing Top sights in Bologna, etc. */

body.page-id-7215 .elementor-element-a8f0323 .elementor-widget-container > div:first-child {
    margin-top: -60px;
    clip-path: margin-box;
}

/* Column containing Useful Links, etc. */

body.page-id-7215 .elementor-element-0ca608c .elementor-widget-container > div:first-child {
    margin-top: -115px;
    clip-path: margin-box;
}
```

**Targeting explanation:**

`body.page-id-7215` - is needed to not take effect on other subpages as well (unique page id)

`.elementor-element-a8f0323` - class name of left column containing *Top sights in Bologna*, *etc.*

`.elementor-element-0ca608c` - class name of right column containing *Useful Links*, *etc.*

`.elementor-widget-container` - the widget container

`div:first-child` - the actual container of the `<iframe>` **(the one we need)**

**Properties explanation:**
I have already explained the properties before (see above).

**Screenshot (CSS applied via DevTools):**
https://i.imgur.com/tEusP11.jpg

**Closing words:**
To come back to what I already mentioned. Using `.page-id-7215`, `.elementor-element-a8f0323` and `.elementor-element-0ca608c` is suboptimal, since these names can change, e.g. with a new installation, etc.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for the help. This is way too advanced for me as I have no idea where to put the code and how to customise it depending on the case. Would it be possible for you to show me a practical example directly on my website?

Comment: It's not that complicated. This is how it looks after applying my workaround (desktop  only): [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/tEusP11.jpg)  So, do you know how to **add custom CSS** to _WordPress_ or thru your _Theme_ or _Elementor_? If not, do you know how to **add code** to the `functions.php` of your _(Child) Theme_ in _WordPress_?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the browser. When an iFrame is loaded from a domain different that that of the webpage, JavaScript access to that iFrame is blocked. CSS too. You might be able to fiddle with the [Content Security Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources) `meta` tags on in your HTML but I doubt it.

You could however use a server like Nodejs and do it. Use Node's `http` module and load/fetch all these widgets then use `jsdom` to get the parts you want and assemble it all into your final webpage.

You could run that node script daily or hourly to save your customized HTML (page) on disk and serve it static.