# Removing the header of a php site in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, header

I tried this code but it didn't work. where is the problem from?

```
<iframe src="https://erfan.ir/farsi/mafatih" height="600" width="900" id="myframe"></iframe>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
(function() {
  if (window.self !== window.top) {
    document.getElementById(".TopHeader").style.display = "none";
  }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Is the content of the `<iframe>` loaded from the same domain?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Ferris No, it is loaded from another domain

Comment: When an <iframe> is loaded from a domain other than that of the web page, JavaScript and CSS access to that `<iframe>` is blocked. So, there is no way to edit a cross domain `<iframe>`. You can manipulate domains within the same level or lower in your domain chain but not for the given situation, that would be **Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)**, which is prohibited for security reasons.

Comment: But what you wanna try is to hide that header by putting the `<iframe` in a container, set it to `position: absolute;` and pull it up with a negative value for `margin-top`. Finally, you also need the `clip-path` property to mask it. Here you can find a [practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276620/20896315) i did. Recently an OP had a similar question where he wanted to remove an `<h2>` tag in an `<iframe>`.